# Somehow can I get the MAC address?

Tags: nsis

I'd like to write the MAC address in a txt file.

I have tried this:

```
FileOpen $4 "$PROGRAMFILES64\OpenVPN\config\auth.txt" w 
###;here filewrite and the MAC address 
FileWrite $4 "client"
FileClose $4
```

Could someone help a bit?

Comment: We cannot have any idea where you are stuck.

Comment: Which MAC address? There can be more than one network card in the machine...

Comment: its not important, just one of the all

Answer (score 1):

There is the [IpConfig plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/IpConfig_plugin) that can help you with `GetNetworkAdapterMACAddress` but you need to know the adapter from which you want the MAC. The [get MAC address from IP](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/IpConfig_plugin#Find_MAC_address_for_a_given_IP_address) example could help you.

Comment: The get MAC address from ip is ok, but if i dont know whats the ip may be, i have to use other plugin like internet ?
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Internet_plug-in